# TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable error from GitHub

Tags: python

I was trying out the practice Pandas for Python problems on GitHub, and one of the things it asked me to do was to convert a column of a DataFrame into floats. This is the code it used:

```
dollarizer = lambda x: float(x[1:-1])
chipo.item_price = chipo.item_price.apply(dollarizer)
```

However, when I copied that code, it gave me a `"TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable"` message.

Comment: Can you try printing out the value of that column from a row? You're trying to convert things that are already floats into floats, so you can't slice it(`[1:-1]`). @juanpa.arrivillaga you're thinking of `float is not callable`

Comment: @CoryMadden aha, you are right.

Comment: huh. I must have already converted it to float at some point. Idk when that happened, but thanks!